# C programming: Bag of words program, need help double pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to complete a bag of word program and i am stuck on a particular function that uses double pointers.

```
char *get_word( char **string_ptr )
{
    char *word;
    int i;

    word = malloc(919); /* Assign memory space for storying gathered characters */
    i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(*string_ptr); i++) /* sort through double pointer */
    {
        if(((**string_ptr) != '\0') && (isalpha(**string_ptr) == 0))
        {
            *string_ptr += 1;       
        }
        else if((**string_ptr) == '\0')
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    *string_ptr += strlen(*string_ptr); 

    return word;
}
```

this function is called into the main.c

```
int main()
{
  char *sentence = "#The quick brown fox jumped over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."; /* test sentence */
  char *word;  /* pointer to a word */

  printf( "sentence = \"%s\"\n", sentence );  /* show the sentence */

  while (*sentence)  /* while sentence doesn't point to the '\0' character at the end of the string */
  {
    word = get_word( &sentence );  /* this will allocate memory for a word */
    printf( "word = \"%s\"; sentence = \"%s\"\n", word, sentence );  /* print out to see what's happening */

    free(word);  /* free the memory that was allocated in get_word */
  }

  return 0;
}
```

At the moment i able to get the function to print out:

```
sentence = "#The quick brown fox jumped over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
word = ""; sentence = ""
```

The sentence after the fist call is: 
"The quick brown fox jumped over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
so i believe i am removing the symbols correctly but i am also removing a space that needs to stay.

The final product i am looking for is:

```
sentence = "#The quick brown fox jumped over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
word = "The"; sentence = " quick brown fox jumped over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
word = "quick"; sentence = " brown fox jumped over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
word = "brown"; sentence = " fox jumped over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
word = "fox"; sentence = " jumped over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
word = "jumped"; sentence = " over 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
word = "over"; sentence = " 23&%^24 the lazy dogs."
word = "the"; sentence = " lazy dogs."
word = "lazy"; sentence = " dogs."
word = "dogs"; sentence = "."

word = "(null)"; sentence = ""
```

Sorry for the long post. I will appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: The condition `i < **string_ptr` is technically valid, but it does not appear to make much sense.  What are you actually trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I fixed my mistake i believe. i am just trying to iterate though the passing argument, so i can take a look at each individual character

Comment: @coderredoc do most of the errors involve my use of double pointers **string_ptr ? i am reading K&R second edition at the moment to learn about double pointers, but i still do not fully understand how to use them

Comment: @user9339337.: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do? It will help me in answering.

Comment: @coderredoc I have added the final output to the question

Comment: Have you included the right code in the question - I cannot see any where in `get_word` that actually populates `word` with any content.

Comment: A relevant article from Eric Lippert: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @ChrisTurner I have included the right code, i did not post any code that populates "word" because everything i have done will not work. This is just the basic code that i know works and i was hoping i could have someone walk me through it,  previously i have used 'strncpy(word, *string_ptr, 1);' to populate word

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < strlen(*string_ptr); i++)` ;; This is not the way to find the end of a string. Throw it away and write your own code.

Comment: @joop what about using while(*string_prt) and increment within the code using *string_prt += 1;

Comment: `word = malloc(919);`  is allocated, never initialized nor used and still returned. Complete nonsense.

Comment: @joop could you point me to a post that will help me make my use of malloc make sense? Is the reason my use of malloc is complete nonsense is because i have not assigned any characters to word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with the function as currently written.

This is a poor way to loop over a string. It is recalculating the length of the remaining string at the end of each iteration.

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(*string_ptr); i++) /* sort through double pointer */
```

The better way to do this, is to either store the results of `strlen()` in a variable or even better, make use of the knowledge that a string will always end in a `NUL` like this

```
for(;**string_ptr!='\0';(*string_ptr)++)
```

Allocating memory for `word` at the beginning of the function is a bad idea. Firstly, you have no idea how much memory you'll need and whilst 919 bytes is probably going to be enough, you don't need to guess as once you've got a word, you should know how long it is. Also your code returns with `NULL` under certain conditions, meaning that the memory allocated will be lost.

```
word = malloc(919); /* Assign memory space for storying gathered characters */
```

This line is skipping `string_ptr` to the very end of the string so you'll never get more than one result.

```
*string_ptr += strlen(*string_ptr);
```

The way to do what you're trying to do is to, firstly keep track of where the word starts and then find the end of it. You'll then know exactly how much memory you need to allocate (remembering the extra byte to store the `NUL`). Here is a possible example of how to do it

```
char *get_word(char **string_ptr)
   {
   char *start;
   char *word=NULL;
   unsigned int word_len;

   // Return NULL if there is no string to process
   if((string_ptr==NULL)||(*string_ptr==NULL)||(**string_ptr=='\0'))
      {
      return NULL;
      }

   // Skip over any non-alpha characters
   while((**string_ptr!='\0')&&(!isalpha(**string_ptr)))
      {
      (*string_ptr)++;
      }

   if(**string_ptr=='\0')
      {
      return NULL;
      }

   // Make note of where this word starts
   start=*string_ptr;

   while(isalpha(**string_ptr))
      {
      (*string_ptr)++;
      }


   word_len=(*string_ptr)-start;
   if(word_len)
      {
      word=malloc(word_len+1);
      strncpy(word,start,word_len);
      word[word_len]='\0'; // Always NUL terminate strings when using strncpy()
      }
   return word;
   }
```

Since it returns `NULL` in some cases, you should also make sure the code calling it checks to see if the result is `NULL` and act accordingly rather than assuming it's always got a string. Calling `free(NULL)` is never a good idea.

Comment: "free(NULL) is never a good idea)", that's a bit of an exaggeration considering the standard says it's fine.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Thank you for the help. Your comments on it have made things very clear.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 Probably, but if you get into the habit of freeing variables without knowing what they contain, you'll run into problems eventually

Comment: @ChrisTurner for the malloc, did you gather the pointer position using the variable *start and then you subtracted that from the total length of *sting_ptr. you did this to only malloc the length of the current sting being copied into *word? That way more memory is not used than needed?

Comment: @MyUsername112358 thanks for the insight, free(NULL) will be OK this time because i have a file that i am testing that contains words. I know what i will be testing

Comment: @user9339337 No, because if you subtract two pointers that are both pointing within the same string you get the length between them. For the first word, `start` will be pointing at the 2nd character and `*string_ptr` will be pointing at the 5th giving `word_len` as 3, so you need to allocate 4 bytes.